# Selenium can't find xpath or css selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape [this](https://www.sephora.com/ca/en/shop/face-makeup) site that has pagination. The problem I'm facing is having selenium locate the next button.

What I've tried:

```
next_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    'ul[class="css-12ke8jn e65zztl0"] button[aria-label="Next"]').click()
```

and

```
page_amount = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/main/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/nav/ul/button').click()
```

None of these work and I'm kinda stuck. The reason I'm using aria-label for the first one is because when the next button is selected the previous button changes to the same class as the next button. Note: The button is inside a ul.

Comment: Where you wanna press next buddy?

Comment: the 'next' button is just an arrow at the bottom of the page if that's what you're asking.

Comment: your css is correct whats the iisue you are facing ?

Comment: selenium won't click the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not work finding the element because it's not visible in UI - it is loaded but not visible, the easiest way is to move to that element and click on it.

```
next_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[aria-label=\'Next\']')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(next_button).perform()
next_button.click()
```

Comment: Sorry for marking this correct so late. I was trying other solutions and yours worked! Also why did you put '\' in the aria-label?

Comment: The CSS selector value is - [aria-value=‘Next’] and the css selector method from Python also uses single quotes to declare the parameter and in order to work we need to escape the single quote from the css selector. Test it by removing the \ from the code - you’ll get an errror

Answer (score 1):

next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="css-1lkjxdl eanm77i0"]').click()

You was using xpath variable and finding it by css. for css selector you have to use the class (.css-1lkjxdl) and use the above code it will work and accept the answer. Thanks!!

Comment: How did you get that xpath? The button never gives that when it's enabled or disabled. Your solution works but how..

Comment: I only searched your query using inspect and found the xpath by right click and copy xpath

Answer (score 0):

`aria-label` is an attribute, not an element.

Your xpath should be fixed as follow:

```xml
button[@aria-label="Next"]
```

To find this button anywhere in the page, you can try:

```xml
//button[@aria-label="Next"]
```

Then, you can try:

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Next"]')
```

Comment: For the css_selector I got 'Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified' and for xpath I just got `None`

Comment: Do you use `find_element_by_xpath`?

Comment: Yes and I also tried `find_element_by_css_selector`